# SpringCloudStream function.definition with SpringBoot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

After Upgrading spring from 2.x to 3.x the resolving of configuration variables somehow changed.

In SpringBoot 2.x.x the variable `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` could be resolved by Spring to the variable `spring.cloud.function.definition`.

In SpringBoot 3.x.x this is no longer possible. Only the "correct" variable `spring.cloud.function.definition` can be resolved.

Does anyone know why the Variable `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` could be resolved before (in SpringBoot 2.x.x)? Also what triggered the change? The Changelogs for SpringBoot 3.0 and 3.1 do not mention anything in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` has been removed from Spring Cloud Stream `4.0.x` versions in preference to `spring.cloud.function.definition`. You can find details about it in the Spring Cloud Stream [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_overview).